# JPA/Hibernate - shared primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, jpa, jpa-2.0

I wanted to create bidirectional one to one relationship with shared primary key.

As it is stated here [JPA Hibernate One-to-One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787698/jpa-hibernate-one-to-one-relationship) I have:

```
@Entity
public class UserProfileInformation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "customForeignGenerator")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
        name = "customForeignGenerator",
        strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "userEntity")
    )
    long id;

    private long itemsPerPage;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="userProfileInformation")
    private UserEntity userEntity;
...}

@Entity
@Table(name = "UserTable")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String publicName;

    private String password;

    private String emailAddress;

    private String name; 

    private boolean active;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private UserProfileInformation userProfileInformation;
...}
```

now, when I try to persist my user in the database, I am getting `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class pl.meble.taboret.model.UserProfileInformation`. Is it because, when userProfileInformation is persisted to the database userEntity doesn't have id generated at that point?

Also, what can I do to create bidirectional relationship with shared primary key in my example?

EDIT:
Requested code, this is simple controller to test the operation of persisting UserEntity.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String t(Model model){
        UserEntity entity=new UserEntity();
        entity.setActive(false);
        entity.setEmailAddress("a");
        entity.setName("name");
        entity.setPassword("qqq");
        entity.setPublicName("p");
        UserProfileInformation p = new UserProfileInformation(entity);
        entity.setUserProfileInformation(p);
        userDao.addUser(entity);
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you are creating/saving the UserProfileInformation entity.  Are you setting the userEntity reference correctly? Also check if changing the type from long to Long works.

Comment: I added the code to the edited first post, also, changing type from long to Long didn't solve the issue.

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027623/how-do-i-properly-cascade-save-a-one-to-one-bidirectional-relationship-on-prima. I think it something to do with which side is the owning side - you probably need to swap the mappedBy & PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Comment: I read this post, but the thing is, mapped by is pointing to mark the non-owning side of association. It is strange to me that I should use mapped by on the UserEntity side, which is the owning side imo. I just can't wrap my head around this so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the id generation strategy. For hibernate `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` translates into a `native` identifier generation. This means that hibernate expects an `identity` id field for the UserTable.

I don't know exactly how `SQLite` works in terms of identity columns, but it seems from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989821/identity-column-maximum-value-in-sqlite-dbs) is a little different (see the second answer).

Anyway if you plan to run your application on multiple databases is better for portability to change the id generation strategy from `GenerationType.AUTO` and use hibernate enhanced generators: `SequenceStyleGenerator` or `TableGenerator`. See [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#portability-idgen) in the hibernate documentation.

**EDIT:**

I tried to reproduce your problem, and it seems that SQLite dialect is not among the officially supported [hibernate dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-dialects). Meanwhile I tested your case with the [H2 embeded database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and it works as expected: your mappings are correct.

If you are using an unofficial SQLite dialect it might be a bug with this dialect.

Comment: I don't know if this is a problem strictly with id generation. Before I didn't have UserProfileInformation class, and I could persist UserEntity with no problems.

Comment: if you enable hibernate sql logs what sqls do you see when persisting the user entity? Just before the exception.

Comment: I have sql logs enabled, there is no sql visible. The exception is `null id generated for:class pl.meble.taboret.model.UserProfileInformation`, and because I am saving UserEntity and I have Cascade on all, Hiberante wants to store UserProfileInformation first, but he can't, because there is no id in the corresponding UserEntity. When I remove the `@GeneratedValue` from both of the classes, and manually set the id in UserEntity, everything is persisting ok.

Comment: Also, as I said in my previous comment, if I manually set Id of UserEntity I am getting this sql log `Hibernate: 
    /* insert pl.meble.taboret.model.UserProfileInformation
        */ insert 
        into
            UserProfileInformation
            (itemsPerPage, id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert pl.meble.taboret.model.UserEntity
        */ insert 
        into
            UserTable
            (active, emailAddress, name, password, publicName, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
` so we see here that UserProfileInformation is stored first.

Comment: what hibernate and SQLite version? I'll set up small project to test your use case.

Comment: Hibernate - 3.6.0. SQLite - 3.7.2

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL dialect found somewhere on the net. Thanks then, for clearing it up. I was mighty confused why the solutions that were provided everywhere didn't seem to work for me. I wasn't suspecting sql dialect though.